# A communication network between three locations, with probability of failure for each link

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

#### Problem statement

Consider a communication network between three locations X, Y and Z. Assume there are links between each location and each link has a probability of failing as shown in the following table:

```
Link      Probability of Failure
 XY             0.1
 YZ             0.2
 XZ             0.5
```

Let E be the event that location X is able to send a message to location Z (i.e., either via the link XZ or via Y using links XY and YZ). Determine P(E), the probability that the message has a route from X to Z by answering the following questions.

Deﬁne a sample space S consisting of 3-tuples representing the three links (XY; Y Z; XZ). If a
link is working, assign it the value 1 and assign it 0 if the link is failing. List all outcomes in S.

#### Progress

Trying to define the sample space here... So from x to z there are two options (xy,yz) and xz. For xz we can just draw 2 options a fail and a pass, but for xy we have to draw out 10 option with 9 passes and 1 fail and then 5(yz) for each of those options. Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: The sample space here is just all the 3-tuples from the set $\{0,1\}$. For example, define three random variables: $A,B,C$ (weird because you already have denoted something else in the problem with $X,Y,Z$). Let $A$ be the Random variable indicating the link condition between two points $X,Y$. It takes values $0,1$ with probabilities as given in the problem. The same way, define for $Y,Z$ and $Z,X$.

Comment: I am lost could you eloaborate im totally new to this like a small example

Answer (score 2):

We have in the problem $3$ Random variables i.e. the variables that indicate whether the link between a pair of locations is working or not. Define the $3$ random variables as $A,B,C$. From the problem description, these random variables are **Bernoulli** (for definition of random variables and their types, I'm assuming you have some introduction to them) because they can take on $2$ values i.e. ${0,1}$. Let $0$ indicate a failure of link. Now the probability mass function $p$ for the random variable $A$, where $A$ is the random variable denoting the link condition between $X,Y$, is:$$p_A(A=a)=\left\{\begin{array}{} 0.1 & a=0 \\ 0.9 & a=1\end{array} \right.$$Likewise the other $2$ Random variables can also be defined. Now the task in hand is to first determine the sample space. **Sample Space** is the collection of all elementary outcomes of an experiment. It is composed of all possible individual **events** that can happen when the experiment is conducted. Here in our example, the **experiment** is just the presence or absence of links between the 3 points. We have $3$ random variables which indicate any such particular event. For example, $$\{A=0,B=1,C=0\}=\text{Event that link between XY is bad, YZ is good, XZ is bad}$$
I'll let you figure out all the possible events for this particular **Sample space** under consideration. The next task in hand is to figure out the probability that $X$ can speak to $Z$ either directly or indirectly. The following need to be done to figure this out:

1. Look at the sample space; see all the events that can lead to a path for transmission from $X$ to $Z$.
2. Find the probability of each of them happening separately, an example calculation is as follows: (assuming that the links work independently of each other)$$\mathbb{P}[\{A=0,B=1,C=0\}]=\mathbb{P}[\{A=0\}]\mathbb{P}[\{B=1\}]\mathbb{P}[\{C=0\}]$$
   where $\mathbb{P}$ stands for probability. The above is due to **independence** of random variables i.e. the link condition between $X,Y$ is irrelevant to the link condition between $Y,Z$ and also to $Z,X$. Simply speaking, the links fail on their own randomly without other links influencing them.
3. Add all the probabilites that you found in step $2$. This step is valid because the **events** you're considering are **disjoint**. At any time, the link conditions take on only one value. The event $\mathbf{E}$ in question is composed of multiple disjoint events and therefore, $$\mathbb{P}[\mathbf{E}]=\mathbb{P}[\{E_1\cup E_2,\dots,\cup E_n\}]=\mathbb{P}(\{E_1\}]+\mathbb{P}(\{E_2\}]+\dots+\mathbb{P}(\{E_n\}]$$ where $E_i$'s indicate the different events that can lead to a transmission between $X$ and $Z$.

If you do not have any exposure to **Random variables** and **probability mass functions**, just go through the following to get rid of the definitions:

1. Let $A,B,C$ stand as $3$ letters denoting the link condition between the pairwise communication points.
2. $A$ is assigned a $0$ if the link is bad or a $1$ if the link is good. Now form the following table for each of the letters and the values that they can take with their corresponding probabilities. $$\begin{array}{c|c}A & \text{Probability that A takes on the value} \\ 0 & 0.1 \\ 1 & 0.9\end{array}$$
   Similarly, form the tables for $B,C$.
3. The **sample space**, denoted by $\Omega$, is just all the possible combinations of the values of $A,B,C$. $$\Omega=\{\{000\},\{001\},\dots,\{111\}\}$$
4. The rest of the question is straight forward as explained in the first $3$ initial steps.